# Upper bound for $n$ balls in $m$ bins

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

When placing *k* balls randomly into *k* bins we can bound the number of balls that falls into any bin by

$$p \leq \frac{3\ln(k)}{\ln(\ln(k))}$$

and this bound fails to hold with probability $\leq$ $\frac1k$

However, what if we have *n* balls and *m* bins where $n \neq m$ ?
Is there a way to bound this as well?

Comment: Is $p$ the number in a pre-selected bin or  the number in the bin with the most balls or something else?

Comment: p is the upper bound of the bin with the most balls